# Unity VisualStudio Bluetooth weird behaviour

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I am working on a Unity project that uses Bluetooth to connect to external devices. I created a C# method that has BluetoothDevice as one of the parameters. Initially the class compiled fine, but suddenly I am getting errors.

I created the following class:

```
public class ScannerCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public ScannerCallback() : base("com.....android.sdk.interfaces.ScannerCallback") { }

    public void onScanned(BluetoothDevice device, int signalStrength)
    {
        Debug.Log("Scanner callback device: " + device
        + " strength="+signalStrength.ToString());
    }
}
```

This gave an error on BluetoothDevice and one of the suggested solutions was to install a new package or similar. I don't remember which package.
After that the BluetoothDevice class was recognized and autocomplete let me select device.deviceId in the Debug line. I think it also introduced
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth

AFter going back to Unity I suddenly got namespace errors on Windows.Devices.Bluetooth and it was asking if I was missing a using directive.
But when I go back to Visual Studio it tells me that the using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth is unnessecasry and the BluetoothDevice class is no longer recognized.

I dont recall what package was installed, so I can't remove it. And I dont know where it went, in the project dependencies I only see System.Windows

I hope someone recognises this and can help me.

[Edit] I tried to reproduce the process in a different Unity project, but I immediately get the namespace issues, I no longer get the suggested fix to install something new, so thats why I think I installed something in Visual Studio rather than in the project.